# Writing each element of nested list into separate column of CSV

Tags: python

I have 3 lists of n length that I want to combine into one list, then combine all the nth indexes together in a list, and produce the output with each element in a separate column in a csv file

```py
list_1 = ["john", "peter", "steve", "mike", "paul"]
list_2 = ["green", "red", "blue", "purple", "orange"]
list_3 = [["dog", "cat"], "rabbit", "dog", "", ["cat", "mouse", "elephant"]
```

So far I've used:

```py
combined_list = list(map(list, zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)))
```

to combine the lists into one.

If I try:

```py
for items in combined_list:
    writer.writerow(items)
```

I get:

```py
john,green,"['dog', 'cat']"
peter,red,rabbit
steve,blue,dog
mike,purple,
paul,orange,"['cat', 'mouse', 'elephant']"
```

Expected output:

```py
john, green, dog, cat
peter, red, rabbit
steve, blue, dog
mike, purple, 
paul, orange, cat, mouse, elephant
```

(with each element in a separate column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isinstance` to check if the last item is a list if so extend else use the list as it is.

**Ex:**

```
list_1 = ["john", "peter", "steve", "mike", "paul"]
list_2 = ["green", "red", "blue", "purple", "orange"]
list_3 = [["dog", "cat"], "rabbit", "dog", "", ["cat", "mouse", "elephant"]]

combined_list = list(map(list, zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)))
for items in combined_list:
    if isinstance(items[-1], list):              #Check if last element is list. 
        writer.writerow(items[:-1] + items[-1])
    else:
        writer.writerow(items)
```

Comment: if  list at second or first position what will happen.

Comment: in OP's case only the last list might contain lists. But if other list can have sublist the they will have to scan all. Point here is to use `isinstance` to detect the object type

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using a double list comprehension with conditions :

```
list_1 = ["john", "peter", "steve", "mike", "paul"]
list_2 = ["green", "red", "blue", "purple", "orange"]
list_3 = [["dog", "cat"], "rabbit", "dog", "", ["cat", "mouse", "elephant"]]
combined_list = list(map(list, zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)))

# This function will help us differentiate strings from lists
def length(y):
    if isinstance(y, str):
        return 'i'
    else:
        return y

# We will store the lists inside a dictionary
lists = {}
for i in range (len(list_1)):
    # If we have a string we store the string otherwise we iterate
    # on the list
    lists[i] = [y if isinstance(y, str) else x 
                for y in combined_list[i] for x in length(y)]
```

---

Output :

```
{0: ['john', 'green', 'dog', 'cat'],
 1: ['peter', 'red', 'rabbit'],
 2: ['steve', 'blue', 'dog'],
 3: ['mike', 'purple', ''],
 4: ['paul', 'orange', 'cat', 'mouse', 'elephant']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ["john", "peter", "steve", "mike", "paul"]
list_2 = ["green", "red", "blue", "purple", "orange"]
list_3 = [["dog", "cat"], "rabbit", "dog", "", ["cat", "mouse", "elephant"]]
alllist=[[l1,l2,l3] for l1,l2,l3 in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3)]

for l in alllist:
 re=[]
 [re.extend(item) if isinstance(item,list) else re.append(item) for item in l]
 print(",".join(re))
```

Result

```
john,green,dog,cat
peter,red,rabbit
steve,blue,dog
mike,purple,
paul,orange,cat,mouse,elephant
```